# Subform does not display in Form view

Tags: sql, ms-access, subform, table-relationships

I have a subform that is derived from a query consisting of a calculated field. It does not display in form view. I have set the Master and child field links and my 'Allow Additions' property is set to yes. What I have discovered is one of the reasons for this is 'The form is based on a table that has no records.' Which is the case. It's of course a one-to-many relationship and the sub-form is the many-side table.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT [Management Accounting table].Date_To_Budgets,
       [Management Accounting table].Date_Returned_To_SCM, 
       [Management Accounting table].Date_To_Assets, 
       [Management Accounting table].Date_Returned_From_Assets, 
       [Management Accounting table].Select_Fund, 
       [Management Accounting table].Project, 
       [Management Accounting table].Select_SubProgramme, 
       [Management Accounting table].Cost_Centre, 
       [Management Accounting table].Item, 
       [Management Accounting table].Supplier, 
       [Management Accounting table].Amount, 
       Sum([Management Accounting table].Amount) AS [Total Amount], 
       SLD_Number
       FROM [Management Accounting table]
       GROUP BY [Management Accounting table].Date_To_Budgets, 
                [Management Accounting table].Date_Returned_To_SCM, 
                [Management Accounting table].Date_To_Assets,
                [Management Accounting table].Date_Returned_From_Assets, 
                [Management Accounting table].Select_Fund,
                [Management Accounting table].Project,
                [Management Accounting table].Select_SubProgramme, 
                [Management Accounting table].Cost_Centre, 
                [Management Accounting table].Item, 
                [Management Accounting table].Supplier, 
                [Management Accounting table].Amount,
                SLD_Number;
```

Comment: Take a look at your own question. Do you find it easy to read and understand? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query with `GROUP BY` is by definition read-only. See e.g. [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html).

So it doesn't matter that the 'Allow Additions' property is set to yes - you won't be able to enter data into a subform based on this query.

=> If the query shows no records, your subform will be completely empty.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate a field without using a group by clause? I need to display a total amounts field, now I don't know how to do it with this group by issue.

Comment: You could use a `DSum()` expression, then only that column would be read-only. But you can only edit single records, so I don't understand how a sum per row would be of any use?